# Open dialog box to choose an image from the computer when clicking on a form field

Tags: javascript, pdf

I have a pdf form and I want to be able to add an image from computer when clicking on a button. Now I found out that I can add an action when pressing a button on the PDF form, but I would need a javascript to open a dialog box to choose the image I want to add.

I am very good at VBA programming, but I never tried Javascript and have no idea where to start. I think I should use "IText", but I still haven't tried anything really tbh

Edit: I tried this: 
event.target.buttonImportIcon();

I get the dialog box and choose the image, but it does not appear on the pdf afterwards

Edit 2: I changed the layout to something other than "Label only" and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

To do this, add a button to your pdf form. In its properties, Under options, change the layout to something other than "label only". Under actions, choose "execute from javascript" and add this code: event.target.buttonImportIcon();